# Передача аргументов в функцию через |

Tags: c++, c

Частенько вижу, что аргументы в функцию передаются так:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK)
```

К указанным параметрам можно добавить и другие, также разделив их вертикальной чертой `|`. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает.

Comment: Это не несколько аргументов, это один аргумент. `SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK` — это одно число.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

операция | - стандартная во многих языках операция побитового `ИЛИ`. Т.е. она применима к 2 числам и для каждого бита будет выполнено побитовое или. Пример:

3<sub>10</sub> | 10<sub>10</sub> = 0011<sub>2</sub> | 1010<sub>2</sub> = 1011<sub>2</sub> = 11<sub>10</sub>.

Это особенно удобно при использовании флагов как констант - степеней 2.

Например у нас есть `FLAG_A = 1`<sub>10</sub>, `FLAG_B = 2`<sub>10</sub>, `FLAG_C = 4`<sub>10</sub> и так далее.
Тогда `FLAG_A | FLAG_C` = 5<sub>10</sub> и в обратную сторону, 5<sub>10</sub> можно получить *только* такой комбинацией.

P.S. в случае с флагами безболезненно заменяется на обычный +, но смотрится не так красиво.

Comment: `+` плох тем, что можно один и тот же флаг по ошибке два раза указать и это может привести к появлению другого флага, а с `|` такого не произойдет.